# Getting error when passing async function to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angulerjs. I do not understand why this does not work.

```
app.factory('jsonFactory',function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getCustomers = function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`
            }).then(function (response) {
                resolve(response.data);
            });
        });
    }
    return factory;
})

app.controller('JsonController', ['$scope','jsonFactory', async function ($scope, jsonFactory) {
    var data = await jsonFactory.getCustomers();
    console.log(data);
    $scope.customers = data;
    $scope.$apply();

}]);
```

when running this i get this error `TypeError: Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor`

```
app.controller('JsonController', ['$scope','jsonFactory', function ($scope, jsonFactory) {
    jsonFactory.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
        console.log(data);
        $scope.$apply();
    });

}]);
```

But this works fine. why is that? Can't i pass async function to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be rewrited like so:

```
app.factory('jsonFactory',function ($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getCustomers = function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return factory;
})
```

First of all - no need for extra `Promise`, because `$http` is already a promise!

Secondable, no need to call `$scope.$apply`. If you want some service method to be called when controller inits, you better create `activate` function, which makes more sense semantically.

```
app.controller('JsonController', ['$scope','jsonFactory', function ($scope, jsonFactory) {
    function activate() {
        jsonFactory.getCustomers().then(function (data) {
            $scope.customers = data;
        });
    }
    activate();
}]);
```

Here is a good [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) about when you should call `$apply` and how.